# Packing bits after masking in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Assume I have a number and I want to interpret every other bit as a new number, e.g.

```
uint16_t a = 0b1111111000000001;
uint16_t mask = 0xAAAA; // 0b1010101010101010
```

I now want to be able to get every other bit packed into two 8 bit variables, like

```
uint8_t b = a & mask ... //  = 0b11110000
uint8_t c = a & ~mask ... // = 0b11100001
```

Is there an efficient way of accomplishing this? I know that I can loop and shift but I am going to do this for a lot of numbers. Even better if I can get both b and c at the same time.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. 0xFF & 0xAA is 0xAA. It is not 0xF0. Start by dropping the binary notation, it is confusing.

Comment: @Lundin he tries to implement the `Compress` function from Hacker's delight.  However, in his question he expresses bigger expectations then it's possible to do.

Comment: You are trying to put the result into a ```uint8_t``` variable, but your initial values are of type ```uint16_t```The compiler would do some casting and you will lose the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print unsigned char as 2-digit hex value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344814/how-to-print-unsigned-char-as-2-digit-hex-value-in-c)

Comment: @alinsoar How does the compress function work? Do you have a reference? I only find compression algorithms..

Comment: @vasile_t Yes, I want to extract every other bit and squeeze them together into a new smaller number

Comment: @Noxet Hacker's delight

Comment: @alinsoar Ah yes, thank you. That is what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can precompute some tables if you want to avoid too much shifting.

I do it for `a&mask`.  For the other situation it is identical with `a&~mask`.

First, you do a& mask to drop the 1's on the unused positions of a.

Suppose you have `a=a1 0 a2 0 a3 0 a4 0`. You want to get the number `a1 a2 a3 a4`.  There are not many possibilities.

You can have a precomputed vector V of short integers and associate for each entry the corresponding value.

For example, `v[0b10100010]` will be `13`, if the mask is `0b10101010`.

If the precomputed vector is not too large it will stay in cache L1, so it will be very fast, for example, if you split your number in groups of 8 or 16 bits.

Comment: This is a very good idea. The code has to be really fast, and a lookup table might be my best option here.